# ASP.NET Core Docker container only responds when debugging in visual studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

After creating an ASP.NET Core app from web template in Visual Studio and clicking Add Docker Support, it runs fine in debug mode initiated by Visual Studio.

However if debugging is stopped in Visual Studio then the container no longer responds even though it is still running and can be entered via terminal etc. The ports are still listening but it just doesn't work anymore.

**Start debugging**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Stop debugging**

[image]

All other info above remains the same with no indication the container is even aware Visual Studio has stopped. The container is still accessible:

[image]

The mapped ports are still listening so there is a process backing the socket:

[image]

But the site no longer works:

[image]

What is Visual Studio doing to make this container respond? Where is the documentation for it?

Comment: Has anyone verified this answer? I am experience this same exact thing. I did try the suggestion and you can run without Debugging from Visual Studio. It does kick the container into gear cause you can see from the Logs that it initializes. However, if you stop and restart the container from Docker Desktop, you're back to square one. You're forced to go through Visual Studio to start the listeners. Basically, it won't run unless you start from Visual Studio in either Debug Attach mode or Start without Debugging mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75367360/) Visual Studio does some tricks when building for debugging so the image doesn't work without VS. If you build the image yourself with `docker build`, it'll work in Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ctrl+F5 (start without debugging)? also change the settings in Tools-Configuration-Containers then look for the options where it gets rid of the containers on close and set them to false. That allowed me to run my asp page with docker without debug being active in VS22.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by simply

- moving the dockerfile (generated by visual studio) from the **project
  folder** to the **solution folder**, and
- running the 'docker build' command in the solution folder.

Hope that helps.