# Docker container running in Docker Destop after closing Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, containers, platform-independent

I would like to make an API with Visual Studio and put it in a container, to be able to execute in any other computer BUT without using Visual Studio. Just running the container.

I launched Visual Studio 2019, selected a new project with the API template and I got the weatherforecast Web Application example with the controller and the WeatherForeCast class. I launch it with 'IIS' and runs perfect, I run it with 'Docker' and runs great (it create the container and I verify it via Docker Desktop). I try the app writing in Chrome/FireFox/IE: https://localhost:container_port/weatherforecast

After that, if close Visual Studio and I still have the container running, and I try again  https://localhost:container_port/weatherforecast, it doesn't work.
I have checked the ports, I have also stopped the container and run it again (it start with new ports, checked in docekr desktop or with 'docker ps' with power shell) and I try again with https://localhost:container_new_port/weatherforecast and it doesn't work until I start again Visual Studio and click on 'Docker'.
It seems there is a link between the container and Visual Studio, something I don't understand because container are really to be independent from anything.

Other people has the same problem, but no solution worked for me:
[How to access a website running on docker after closing the debug on Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448534/how-to-access-a-website-running-on-docker-after-closing-the-debug-on-visual-stud)
[ASP.NET Core Docker container only responds when debugging in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369751/asp-net-core-docker-container-only-responds-when-debugging-in-visual-studio)
[why is my docker container ASP.NET core app not available after ending debugging in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466334/why-is-my-docker-container-asp-net-core-app-not-available-after-ending-debugging)

¿Any help? If anybody ask you to build an app with visual studio BUT to be run in a container without using  VS, what would you do?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have run into an artifact of the debugging optimizations used in VS: http://aka.ms/containerfastmode. If you do a full build of the Dockerfile (right click in VS, or build from the command line [Note: the build context is the solution folder by default]) you'll get an image that works w/o VS running.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved by :

1. After Closing the VS Code debug, go to your Container Terminal on Docker Dekstop, and Run `dotnet [MYDLLNAME].dll` .
2. Publish released app manually, create the Dockerfile, and run the docker build and docker run.

this my Dockerfile Reference :

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base WORKDIR /app EXPOSE 80 EXPOSE 443 COPY published/ ./ ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApplication.dll"]`